# Update field using inner join

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to update a field in a table from another table using INNER JOIN. Here is the code:

```
UPDATE TestResults  
INNER JOIN Distractors 
ON TestResults.DistractorID = Distractors.ID 
SET    TestResults.DistractorValue = Distractors.DistractorValue
```

This does not work I don't know why! Any idea? When I run the query I get the following error

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token        in error = INNER ]
```

Comment: Pleace specify database vendor. MSSQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all databases support `join` syntax with `update`.  And when they do, the syntax differs.  Here is a way to do your query without an explicit `join` using standard SQL:

```
UPDATE TestResults  
    set DistractorValue = (select max(d.DistractorValue)
                           from Distractors d
                           where TestResults.DistractorValue = d.DistractorValue
                          )
where exists (select 1
              from Distractors d
              where TestResults.DistractorValue = d.DistractorValue
             );
```

The `max()` is only needed if there could be more than one matching row.

The `where` is only needed if the `join` is intended to do filtering as well as matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TestResults
SET TestResults.DistractorValue = Distractors.DistractorValue
FROM TestResults
INNER JOIN Distractors 
ON TestResults.DistractorID = Distractors.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the Updated table in the Inner join clause

ex:

```
  UPDATE TestResults  
    SET    TestResults.DistractorValue = Distractors.DistractorValue
    FROM TestResults INNER JOIN Distractors 
    ON TestResults.DistractorID = Distractors.ID
```